# Layer 2-3 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Module MTU 9000

Tags: mtu

I have this device Layer 2-3 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Module for IBM eServer BladeCenter and I need to know how to enable jumbo frames to 9000 if this is possible. I searched a lot but I was unable to find any info but that the jumbo frames are supported. 
Does anyone know how  it can be done, and if it is possible to set MTU of 9000 per VLAN, interface etc !?

End how I can see if the jumbo-frames are enabled. I am using the user interface that is not like on cisco devices.

Like: /c/l2/vlan etc

How can I see if jumbos are enabled using this interface!?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Blade OS - the command reference is a good place to start.

To see if jumbo support is enabled per vlan, navigate to

```
/info/l2/vlan
```

To enable jumbo support per vlan, navigate to

```
/cfg/l2/vlan <VLAN number>
```

I don't see anything for more granular control.
Source: http://bladenetwork.net/userfiles/file/PDFs/IBM_GbE_L2-7_Command_Ref.pdf

Comment: When I am going to cfg/l2/vlan <vlan number> I get this (not jumbo command is present):       pvlan    - Protocol VLAN Menu
     privlan  - Private-VLAN Menu
     name     - Set VLAN name
     stg      - Assign VLAN to a Spanning Tree Group
     add      - Add port to VLAN
     rem      - Remove port from VLAN
     def      - Define VLAN as list of ports
     bwidth   - Bandwidth Management
     mgmt     - Enable/Disable this VLAN as additional management VLAN
     ena      - Enable VLAN
     dis      - Disable VLAN
     del      - Delete VLAN
     cur      - Display current VLAN configuration

Comment: Do you have a part number for the module?

Comment: I have this, if this is it: PCBA Part Number:      317857-C

Comment: is very strange because the documentation says that the jumbos are supported, but there is no command to enable it or disable or set the value

Comment: Can you send a few jumbo frames and check statistics?

Comment: when I send a ping from a server on a blade vers the ip  ie: 192.168.1.25 that is in a specific vlan (ie: vlan20) as: ping -s 9000 192.168.1.25 it fails. when I do with 1500 it pass. the ping is performed from a server in a blade, ie: lame 5 server, and the ip 192.168.1.25 is configured as gateway on my  Layer 2-3 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Module for IBM eServer BladeCenter that is connected to a nexus device. this is still an internal communication and this is strange that does not support more then 1500.

Comment: Is your server running in a VM?

Comment: no, is not a virtual machine, if you mean that

Comment: Are you sure jumbos are dropped at the switch port?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20083/discussion-between-ipermo-and-alib-15).

Comment: well the ping with 9000 fails and the 1500 are successful